# filtering on multiple conditions spring xd

Tags: spring-xd, spring-el

I want to filter out payload if it contains following error codes 202048
 202049 200003

```
filter --expression=payload.contains('202048')||payload.contains('202049')||payload.contains('200003')

Can i put or condition in my expression || is my or
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [SpEL language reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-operators-logical).

Use `OR` (or `or`).

You need spaces around the `or` so you need to quote the whole expression; since the module is likely within a string, you will need to escape the literal quotes. For example:

```
xd:>stream create foo --definition "time | 
    filter --expression='payload.endsWith(\"0\") OR payload.endsWith(\"1\")'| log" --deploy
```

Comment: When using flo (the admin UI), use `''` instead of `\"` - `...endswith(''0'')...`.