# Spring XD - Logical operators in SpEL expression and filters

Tags: filter, spring-xd, spring-el

I would to create a filter like this

```
file --outputType=text/plain --dir=someDir --mode=lines | filter --expression='payload.contains(\"request url\") AND payload.contains(\"request method\")' | log
```

So, i would to visualize on the console the lines which contain `request URL` and `request method`.

I made this stream in according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34088075/filtering-on-multiple-conditions-spring-xd/34089334#34089334)

Unfortunatelly i've this error:

> .... Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException;
> nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are: PropertyAccessException 1:
> org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property
> 'expressionString' threw exception; nested exception is
> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1065E:(pos
> 17): unexpected escape character.

**EDIT:** i've deployed the stream via Flo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version are you using? I just tried this with 1.3.1 with no problems...

```
xd:>stream create foo --definition "tcp --outputType=text/plain | filter --expression='payload.contains(\"foo\") AND payload.contains(\"bar\")' | log" --deploy 

$ telnet localhost 1234
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
abc
foobar
```

Result:

```
2017-03-25T08:59:57-0400 1.3.1.RELEASE INFO xdbus.foo.1-1 sink.foo - foobar
```

**EDIT**

When using flo (admin UI), use `''` instead of `\"` ...

```
foo = tcp --outputType=text/plain | filter --expression='payload.contains(''foo'') AND payload.contains(''bar'')' | log
```

Comment: I'm using 1.3.1. After your message i've deployed the same stream of my question via shell (first i've deployed via Flo). With shell it's all ok, via Flo the same identical stream not works and returns the error of the question.

Comment: Use `''` instead of `\"` with flo - see the update to my answer (I just tested it).

Comment: Now it's all ok!! Thank you very much!!